# How to make an icon component an object property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In a React component I'm mapping through a list to display the category icons and their names.

```
<List>
    {[
        {
            name: 'Favourites',
            icon: <FavoriteBorderIcon className={classes.icon} />,
        },
        {
            name: 'Explore',
            icon: <ExploreIcon className={classes.icon} />,
        },
        {
            name: 'Watchlist',
            icon: <StarBorderPurple500Icon className={classes.icon} />,
        },
    ].map((category, index) => (
        <ListItem button key={category.name}>
            <ListItemIcon>{category.icon}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={category.name} />
        </ListItem>
    ))}
</List>
```

I want to make the code cleaner and move the array of object to a separate data file. However, I'm getting this error:

[image]

I could make the values for icons strings (this way the error disapears) but how I could display them afterwards?

Comment: try changing `Drawer.data.ts` to `Drawer.data.tsx`.

Comment: anyway, the state/data in Reactjs is intended to be minimal and not contain `tsx` element. you should change your design such as letting the `primaryCategories` contains only `name` and having another component `MyListItemIcon` conditionally renders the actual icon based on `name` props.

Comment: It is a typescript error that say the className property is not a prop of your component you should add className?: string to your components props type

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I like the ideas of changing the structure such as letting the `primaryCategories` contains only `name` and having another component `MyListItemIcon` conditionally renders the actual icon based on `name` props